# What are some ways to sort and load posts into a dynamic php template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I currently have two projects I'm working on, a small flash game site to practice things and get a grasp on some concepts and a blog/game dev advertisement hybrid. My question to you guys is what would be the most efficient way to load posts so I could do things like generate pages with a specified number of entries on them and sort them based on categories I will define later. It may just be my ignorance, but storing each one in a file seems rather inefficient since there will be quite a few of them to store.
example of a basic game "post" from the small flash game site, just really a div container for it all and, and I could add something in like a tag system to sort it out later

```
    <div class="game">
                <a href="games/game.php?game=somegame"><img src="images/somegame.png"></a>
                <div id="content">
                    <a href="games/game.php?game=somegame"><header>Game name</header></a>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Best is to use a database and store your snippets categorized. After that you can get any number of records defined in your query.

Comment: I have to add that you may also store them in an XML file. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the 3 files in a folder on your (local) host and run the index.php - is that what you're looking for?

`/wwwroot/post.tpl`

```
<article id="{$postId}" class="{$postType}">
    <div class="content" style="width:450px;float:left;margin-right:20px;">     
        <h3><a href="single-post.php?id={$postId}">{$postTitle}</a></h3>
        <p>{$postContent}</p>
    </div>
    <a href="single-post.php?id={$postId}"><img style="height:150px;" src="{$postPreviewImage}"></a>
</article><br clear="all"/>
```

`/wwwroot/main.tpl`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>{$pageTitle}</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{$pageH1}</h1>
  <hr>
  Filter posts: 
  <select id="filter">
    <option id="all">Show all posts</option>
    {$filterOptions}
  </select>
  <hr>
  {$posts}
  <script>
    $().ready(function() {
      $("#filter").change(function() {
        for(var b = $(this).find(":selected").attr("id"), d = document.getElementsByTagName("article"), c = 0;c < d.length;c++) {
          var a = d[c];
          "all" === b || b === a.className ? $(a).fadeIn() : b !== a.className && $(a).fadeOut()
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`/wwwroot/index.php`

```
<?php
// get categories from DB
$postCategoriesFromDb = array(
    array(
        'slug' => 'games',
        'name' => 'Games'
    ),
    array(
        'slug' => 'dev',
        'name' => 'Development'
    )
);

// get posts from DB
$postsFromDb = array(
    array(
      'id'      => 1,
      'type'    => 'games',
      'image'   => 'http://openmatt.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Game-On-banner.png',
      'title'   => 'A post about games',
      'content' => 'This is the content of my game post.. lorem ipsum..'
    ),
    array(
      'id'      => 2,
      'type'    => 'dev',
      'image'   => 'http://gregrickaby.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/github-logo.png',
      'title'   => 'A post about development',
      'content' => 'This is the content of my dev post.. lorem ipsum..'
    )
);

// function to populate single post template with post data
function getPostHtml($postData) {
    $html = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/post.tpl');

    $vars = array(
        '{$postId}'           => $postData['id'],
        '{$postType}'         => $postData['type'],
        '{$postPreviewImage}' => $postData['image'],
        '{$postTitle}'        => $postData['title'],
        '{$postContent}'      => $postData['content']
    );

    return strtr($html, $vars);
}

// create HTML for each post
$posts = '';    
foreach ($postsFromDb as $post) {
    $posts .= getPostHtml($post);
}

// create HTML for category filter
$options = '';  
foreach ($postCategoriesFromDb as $cat) {
    $options .= sprintf('<option id="%s">%s</option>', $cat['slug'], $cat['name']);
}

// get main page template
$html = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/main.tpl');

// template vars
$vars = array(
    '{$pageTitle}'     => 'Page title',
    '{$pageH1}'        => 'Hello World!',
    '{$filterOptions}' => $options,
    '{$posts}'         => $posts
);

// output to client
echo strtr($html, $vars);
```

Comment: Wow, I did not need anyone to do it for me, I am not like that, kudos to you. I am actually not THAT bad and could have managed this myself, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Sorry for taking your challange. I just couldn't sleep. And it took only a few mins to write it down. But I'm sure you could have sorted this out on your own! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new in the world of developing (not a problem).
You might want to hunt for a solution that works out of the box.

Things that come to mind: Tumblr, Wordpress etc...

If you really want to hack it yourself, I would advice you to use a "framework" you can see this as an extra layer on top of the programming language, to fill in the gaps / make stuff easier to use.

I can really recommend using laravel (http://laravel.com/docs) it's very simple to use, and the docs will set you up to speed.

Hope it helps

Comment: I would really rather "hack" it in myself, as you said. Right now I would rather do it without a framework, mainly because of the way I learn. I set a goal and I go for it, making myself learn it for later use. Really, I am kind of looking for the better way to store the information rather than load it. Maybe that was not that clear.

Comment: Then I would recommend you to store stuff in a database (check PHP's PDO's docs, to see what DB's are supported and how it should be used).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an XML file like this. There are different ways of reading an XML file. My guesss is you want to read it into Flash. So you would be looking at actionscript.
For that you can easily find information and start learning.
(ie. http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=64 )

It depends on what you want. You can generate the div block with the information out the XML file on the fly.

```
<games>
    <game>
        <name>Some name</name>
        <link>"games/game.php?game=somegame</link>
        <image>"images/somegame.png"</image>
        <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>Second name</name>
        <link>"games/game.php?game=secondgame</link>
        <image>"images/secondgame.png"</image>
        <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
    </game>
</games>
```